# Going to France and Italy - what payment forms are preferred?

Tags: money, paris, payment-cards, rome

Can I get by In Paris and Rome by carrying very little cash and using the credit card for every little souvenir, tour and food purchase? Or should I prefer paying in cash for both Paris and Rome? How widely accepted/common are payments by card?

Comment: You should expect pickpockets in Paris and Rome, the train conductor on the international train I was traveling on quite some tome ago specifically warned about pickpockets in Paris (and I learned that the French word for pickpocket is just the same as the English word, it is just pronounced in a French way). But it would be fun to do an experiment using a wallet filled with monopoly money that you just put in the rear pocket of your trousers and see how long it will last.

Comment: `Should I expect pickpockets to be at all tourist locations?` This part of the question is kinda unanswerable since it's very broad.

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/18198/22140 and http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/44026/22140

Comment: @JoErNanO I'm tempted to create a new question which is just "Should I expect pickpockets at tourist locations?" and self-answer with "yes".

Answer (score 11):

In France you can almost always pay with a credit card but for small amounts (say up to €10,) cash is often preferred. In Paris cards are a little more often accepted than in small towns off the tourist track.

I have not been in Italy, so not in Rome, but I have heard the same for there.

Get some cash and use your card for the bigger payments. If you are low on cash, check with the restaurant before you start your dinner. Most of the time there will be an ATM near, but you might prefer an other restaurant.

And not all credit cards are as easily accepted as others. Visa and Mastercard work almost everywhere, American Express less and other cards are rare or unheard of.

Best check with your bank that your usual ATM card is ready for use abroad and tell them that you will use it in Europe, and when. Also check with you credit card company. If you have the choice think about replacing your credit card with a chip and pin, as those are the standard in Europe.
Ask about the cost for each use, both for the credit card and the ATM card.

Get about €200 out of the ATM, or from a bank at home, and get some more when you are seeing the end of it. That way you will not be left with a lot of euros. Nor will pick pockets have a feast of your money.

You should expect pick pocket at any touristy place in the world, as well as any busy place. Tourists are an easy target but all people with some money or valuables can find them gone at unexpected times.

Comment: Note that Visa/Mastercard rules prevent merchants from setting a minimum acceptable amount for card payments. Many (small) shops still violate it, but you can often get them to take the card after reminding them about the law.

Comment: In France, I would say the threshold is closer to 10 euros than 20. Some shops (I did not know it was forbidden) may say they refuse cards under 8 to 12 euros, but it is very common to pay with a bank card starting at 5-10 euros and few people use cash above 15.

Comment: You can pay an espresso ("café"), or 1.5€ just fine with VISA in France. No problems whatsoever. And, why should there be any problems? It's not like France is a 3rd world country. I pay **everything** with VISA in France all the time.

Comment: @Damon That's certainly not true everywhere in France...

Comment: The smaller shops can't afford to eat the transaction fees. In the USA, for example, it is common to see a flat rate of $0.25 per transaction plus some percentage of the total transaction. In theory, this means that anything less than $0.27 (or more) will automatically result in a *loss* for the business. Larger businesses can iron those charges out, but a small business might not be so lucky...

Comment: In Europe it is much more common to pay with your debit card, for which the businesses mostly pay a flat fee, so they can afford to accept it for small amounts. Small shops often do not accept credit cards at all. In some countries even supermarkets do not accept credit cards.

Comment: @JonathanReez so far in Italy, every time anyone I know pointed that out, the shopkeeper usually didn't give a damn and still refused to accept it. (would be nice to report them to the credit card company, now that you make me think about it)

Comment: @Lohoris its a bit more tricky - you have to report them to the bank which processes their transactions (the name is usually written on the card terminal).

Comment: If you successfully make a complaint, and the bank tells them off over it, the result will likely be they stop accepting cards at all. So if that's the outcome you want (or that their business fails and is replaced by one that sells more expensive things with higher margins to avoid unprofitable card transactions), then go ahead. But the reason businesses get away with breaking the rule is that most customers can carry a small amount of cash, and wouldn't really benefit from it being enforced, and so *don't* report it.

Comment: @phyrfox There is a transaction fee in taking cash as well!

Comment: *"Get about €200 out of the ATM, and get some more when you are seeing the end of it."*  So, about every 40 minutes, say, when on holiday in France or Italy!  :O

Comment: Not when you use plastic for the big bills. For me €200 lasts a week in Paris.

Comment: @SteveJessop its more convenient to pay by card. As a consumer, I follow the laws and contracts imposed by businesses and governments, and I expect merchants to do the same.

Comment: @JonathanReez: sure, just be aware that the means by which they move into compliance with the rules is more likely to be by no longer accepting your card for any purchases. If your goal is that everyone follows the rules, then it won't matter to you whether you can use your card or not in that store, so it'd be a good outcome. If your goal is to use your card in that store for small purchases then it might not be achievable and no outcome is good.

Comment: I'm really surprised at what people seem to think about Europe. Yes, it's more common to pay with a debit card, but that is solely because unlike in the USA, not every hobo gets 20 credit cards for free. You need to have a clean credit record and a minimum amount of net income to get a credit card, so not everybody has one. But that doesn't mean you can't use it virtually everywhere. I pay with CC in every major supermarket in Germany and virtually _everywhere_ (even that small grocer down the road, and in that cafe round the corner) in France, all the time.

Answer (score 7):

I just got back from a 2 week vacation in Venice, Rome, Amalfi Coast, and Paris on Monday.

First, note that Espressos/Coffee/Pastries, are generally pretty inexpensive in Italy at about 0,50€ - 1,50€. We never even tried paying for something that cheap with a credit card, and I don't think you should either.

We used a couple personal drivers, and they all only accepted cash.

In Venice and Amalfi there were many small vendors who didn't take credit cards, and many others required that you spend at least 10-20€ before they'd take credit.

In Rome we were able to use our credit card everywhere, however, we didn't make it to any of the Artisanal shops during our stay - but from what I've seen from the other places we visited, accepting credit cards would be pretty hit or miss. In Rome, there are TONS of street vendors selling art or selfie-sticks, and I highly doubt they accept credit.

In Paris we used our credit card everywhere and had one Cafe/Bar require we spend at least 10€ so we could use our credit card (we ran out of Euros). It is generally hard to spend less than 10€ in Paris anyway, though. haha.

When asking vendors if they accept credit cards sometimes we would get a question back asking if it was American Express; i'm not sure why they'd ask but my assumption was that not all of the vendors accepted it.

---

#### Unsolicited Advice Section:

Note: get a credit card that doesn't charge a Foreign Transaction Fee (which is usually around 3%). BarclayCardUS has a no annual contract card with 0 foreign transaction fees and a 25,000 point bonus for using it (which you can use on an travel related purchases - including Uber!). You also get extra points back on those travel purchases. The down side is that this card doesn't have a chip and pin, which I noticed frustrates the vendor sometimes. On one of our flights they accepted credit cards but ONLY with chip and pin, which I was told is common in Paris (but didn't experience myself)!

As for converting USD to Euros: we did it at a bank out of necessity/emergency and they charged us about 12%. I did notice that there are places that claim they don't take a commission; just make sure you know the [exchange rate](https://www.google.com/search?q=USD+to+Euro&oq=USD+to+Euro) before you go that route to avoid getting ripped off.

Final note: others have already mentioned the pick-pockets, but I'd like to add that they can be a more brazen than what you see in the movies. One (elderly) family member had his man-purse ripped from his shoulder, and another had his cell phone swiped right from his hands. From what the locals tell me, that's about the worse things that happens in these touristy areas. So, hold on to your stuff tightly and put your valuables in your front pocket only!

Comment: It's a good point that italia is much cheaper than france, these days.  It's basically 2.50 to 3 (or much more) euros for coffee in france now.  My wife recently paid 6.48 euros for two small coca colas in a cafe in a tourist town in france, we were struck by the high price.

Answer (score 6):

Traveling to France (mostly Paris) and Italy (Rome, Venice, Sorrento)

I mostly pay my day-to-day expenses (local transport, lunch, souvenirs...) with cash.

Bigger expenses (mostly restaurants) with my Credit card.

I usually keep 60 to 100 euro with me all the time; I keep 20-ish euro in my front pocket and the rest in the wallet in my back pocket (not really paranoid).

I use the ATM when low on cash. ATM machine are directly usually on the street (even bank machine), just be more careful than usual, pick your cash and quickly put it away (pocket and/or wallet).

I leave the Credit card (and most of the cash) in the hotel room safe; and bring it only if I know I will use it.

Comment: Why is this a good idea? What are the advantages?

Comment: The advantage is that you look like less of a tourist.

Answer (score 6):

Be aware that many places in France will not take a credit card if it doesn't have a chip on it.  These cards are not that common in the US, but are in Europe.  I was able to just call AmEx and get a new card that has a chip, and I believe many US banks will now issue them if you ask.

Answer (score 4):

In France, cards are widely accepted anywhere (and not more in Paris than in rural areas), but in small shops there's often a limit on the amount. In Paris the card is generally refused for anything less than 15€, sometimes 20€ but that's in extreme cases. In rural areas, the limit is more often around 10€.

I live in France, and I almost never carry more than 60€ on cash with me. That's enough to pay for small amounts at the bar or such things. Since you're a tourist, you'll probably make more small payments than I do daily, so might consider carrying more with you. I'd still advise to carry small cash amounts, and withdraw from an ATM when you need more. There is always one nearby in Paris.

I have only spent a few days in Rome, but I did what I'm advising you. I carried small amounts of cash for small expenses, and paid by card for restaurants, museums, etc...

Comment: when you say cards do you mean debit/bank cards or credit cards?

Answer (score 2):

Always have some cash on hand, enough to pay for the restaurant if they don't accept your cards or any cards at all. 
Spread the money among people in your travel group.

Warn your bank so they don't block your cards and bring two different cards if you have them (some circuits like american express aren't accepted everywhere, mastercard or visa are very widespread).

Paris and Rome are typical for pickpockets as are all touristy areas in big cities. Pay attention when withdrawing money from ATMs.

For small payments, using the card is more rare but if you ask they usually do it, in Italy forget about using credit cards for street food or even some small shops because many don't have a machine. 
Depending on the size of your group you need a minimum amount of cash because it can happen that some restaurant doesn't take credit cards, or doesn't have a working POS machine and you don't want to waste time looking for an ATM.

Comment: Whilst I think that `Read up on [...] scams and distraction tactics` is a good piece of advice that any experienced traveller should follow, I condemn your generalisation in that all pickpockets are of Roma ethnicity.

Comment: Yeah, I think this post was a political subjective comment and this website is not for political tribune. I took the freedom to remove these bits to keep the good parts.

Comment: I didn't say that but whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Are you coming from the US?  Is your vacation date at least a few months in the future?  If so, you *might* be able to save a little money by buying your euros now, or dollar-cost averaging them between now and the time you depart.  The exchange rate is pretty favorable right now.  It hasn't been this good in about ten years.

If you do this, you'll be paying for things in cash.  You'll have extra motivation to pay in cash as opposed to plastic if the rate gets less favorable during your vacation.

Comment: Exchanging cash is almost always way more expensive than getting money out of the ATM and than paying with a credit card. Pick-pockets are a serious risk. And if you get too much money and you will have to change back you loose money on it again.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: It's an excellent point that, Thank God, the euro is plummeting a bit, (ie, as any conspiracy theorist will tell you, there is finally a backlash against the US manipulating their crap paper down so low!!)

Comment: @MarkMayo, the question was cash or credit card.  I gave a reason to pick cash.  Please explain to me why you think I didn't provide an answer to the question.

Comment: @user2023861 it's an annoying 'feature' of the site, there's a flag for 'should be a ciarifaction' - eg you were asking him questions IN your answer, which I chose - these should be comments and clarified BEFORE an answer. However, the site then enters in default text of 'this does not provide an answer', which is not what I meant at all :/